# How do I log the latest Git commit when starting a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to log the latest Git commit when starting a Rails app.

I've tried adding an initializer `config/initializers/latest_commit.rb`:

```
latest_commit = `git rev-parse HEAD`
STDOUT.puts "**** latest commit: #{latest_commit}"
```

The initializer is also run during rake tasks, but I do not want the message to be printed for rake tasks, so that rules out `config.after_initialize`.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: I didn't say so in the questions, but it would be best if I could distinguish between starting the Rails console and starting the Rails server, so that the  output is only printed for starting the Rails server.  Further suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if rake is running:

```
running_rake = ::File.basename($0) == 'rake'

unless running_rake
  latest_commit = `git rev-parse HEAD`
  STDOUT.puts "**** latest commit: #{latest_commit}"
end
```

Also I recommend you to put this code somewhere else, for example in environment.rb. Initializers stay for different purposes.